# CSS works when on static site, but zero height divs when ported to Rails app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I've been working on porting a static site I built over to a Rails app for learning + extensibility.

The framework is easy enough to understand, asset pipeline is fine, and assets are loading - but for some reason, I'm seeing odd behaviour in my stylesheets between the two.

Expected: http://briansdonohue.com <-- static, just HTML/CSS

[Screencap from rails app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLypA.png)

Anyway - the stylesheets *appear* to render the same - except for height. The grid elements are rendering at zero height, rather than filling their parent div like on static.

Static CSS - Github Repo: brianshayne/brianshayne.github.io

Rails SCSS - Github Repo: brianshayne/brianshayne-rails

I'm at a loss as to why it's rendering differently.

Comment: Please paste the relevant css and scss links (you have just given the repo names) on github.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but it looks like in your rails version you require stylesheets twice (require_tree and then import) and also you do it in a different order than in your static app.

Comment: @Anand I would have - except the linking limitation. Let's try here.

https://github.com/Brianshayne/BrianShayne.github.io/blob/master/css/main.css
https://github.com/Brianshayne/brianshayne-rails/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/pages.scss

Comment: @MikeIvanov sorry, red herring there - I reversed them to try, and forgot to undo it when I pushed to repo.

require_tree is commented though, in any case.

Comment: @BrianDonohue it's not commented, *= is a system directive processed by rails. You can remove "import" lines and still see all your css included

Comment: @MikeIvanov indeed. That's an odd convention that it would supercede a multi-line comment like that. /shrug

Doesn't help - but at least now they're only pulled once.